# Entra ID auth to Azure SQL VM intermittently fails

Tags: authentication, azure-vm, sql-server-2022, microsoft-entra

We have a number of Azure VMs running SQL server 2022 in our organization.  We create these VMs from a marketplace image that comes with SQL preinstalled.   We then go through the configuration steps to set SQL up to allow for Entra ID auth.  This process is working well on many machines.  I say this just to show that we know how to set this authentication up properly.

There is one particular machine that is having some issues.  It's worth noting that we shut down these VMs at night and turn them back on in the morning at 6:30am, but this is true of all of our VMs. In the mornings around 7:30am-8:00am I connect to SQL using SSMS and run some queries to make sure things are working well. For this particular machine the Entra ID authentication sometimes works and other times does not.  When it does not work I have been able to find these errors in the SQL server log.

Federated Authentication JWT ReadAndValidateToken failed with state: 33, JSON Result ErrorCode: 0 dwError: 12007

Federated Authentication Failed for LibraryType: 2, ErrorState: 133, HRESULT ErrorCode: -2147467259

Eventually the Entra ID auth starts working again without any intervention.  I have gone through and double checked the Entra ID set up, that the VM and SQL VM both have system assigned managed identities and that those identities have Directory Reader permission to our Entra ID.  I can't really figure out why this works sometimes but at other times does not.  Any help is appreciated!